# how to change an image texture midway through animation, or which material the object is using?

Tags: animation, materials

basically I want to have the image texture/material of an object change for a few frames with multiple textures in an animation, I dont want it to slowly ease into it either, i just want it to change instantly, but I cant figure out how to add keyframes to any materials of sorts, And Just duplicating the object and putting a different texture on it is out of the question. Was just wondering if anyone here knew? Thanks in advance :)

Comment: You can animate the fac slider of any mix color or mix shader node.

Answer (score 1):

You can add keyframes to the fields of most shader nodes by hoovering over the field, right clicking, and selecting Add Keyframe from the dropdown menu.  Here's an example where two principled shaders represent the two different materials:

[image: Material showing keyframes on Mix Shader]

I've added keyframes on the Mix Shader so that it switches from 0 to 1.

There are a couple of ways to make the transition sudden.  Here's an easy one.

- Set it up so that you use the top input of your Mix shader as the first material and the bottom as the second.
- Set the timeline to the first frame that you want to use the upper material and set a keyframe to 0
- Set the timeline to the last frame that you want to use the upper material and set a keyframe to 0.
- Set the timeline to the next frame, and set a keyframe to 1.

The switch will be quick.

You can also use the Fcurve editor to change the transition from a gradual one to a sudden one.